# Puppet shows a different version to the puppet-agent package version

Tags: puppet

Why puppet showing different versions in system:

```
[root@localhost ~]# puppet --version
4.7.0
[root@localhost ~]# puppet agent --version
4.7.0
```

But rpm shows diff version for agent and server

```
[root@localhost ~]# rpm -qa | grep puppet
mcollective-puppet-common-1.11.1-1.el7.noarch
puppetlabs-release-22.0-2.noarch
mcollective-puppet-agent-1.11.1-1.el7.noarch
puppet-agent-1.7.0-1.el7.x86_64
puppet-agent-oauth-0.5.1-1.el7.noarch
puppetserver-2.6.0-1.el7.noarch
mcollective-puppet-client-1.11.1-1.el7.noarch
```

Please clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`puppet-agent` is a bundle package containing a number of components, called the All-in-One (AIO) package. Here is some more information on it:

- [Where did everything go in Puppet 4.x?](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/4.8/whered_it_go.html)
- [Say Hello to Open Source Puppet 4!](https://puppet.com/blog/say-hello-to-open-source-puppet-4)

With the RPMs, you can find out the contents of `puppet-agent` and the versions of every component with `rpm -qi puppet-agent`, e.g.

```
# rpm -qi puppet-agent
Name        : puppet-agent
Version     : 1.8.2
Release     : 1.el7
Architecture: x86_64
Install Date: Wed 07 Dec 2016 07:12:31 EST
Group       : System Environment/Base
Size        : 126776210
License     : See components
Signature   : RSA/SHA512, Tue 06 Dec 2016 14:30:51 EST, Key ID 7f438280ef8d349f
Source RPM  : puppet-agent-1.8.2-1.el7.src.rpm
Build Date  : Mon 05 Dec 2016 19:37:56 EST
Build Host  : hk1ldlzw0klwdyo.delivery.puppetlabs.net
Relocations : (not relocatable)
Vendor      : Puppet Labs
URL         : https://www.puppetlabs.com
Summary     : The Puppet Agent package contains all of the elements needed to run puppet, including ruby, facter, hiera and mcollective.
Description :
The Puppet Agent package contains all of the elements needed to run puppet, including ruby, facter, hiera and mcollective.

Contains the following components:
augeas 1.4.0
cpp-hocon 0.1.4
[..]
puppet 4.8.1
[..]
```

The version of "puppet" in the output corresponds to the version of Puppet:

```
# puppet --version
4.8.1
```

You can also find this information summarised online at [puppet-agent: What is it, and what's in it?](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/about_agent.html) with a table of puppet-agent/Puppet version numbers.

Puppet Server is similar. It has its own numbering scheme, where the latest at the time of writing is 2.7.2, and yours is 2.6.0. See [Puppet Server: Release Notes](https://docs.puppet.com/puppetserver/latest/release_notes.html) for information about each version.

The `puppetserver` package does depend on `puppet-agent`, so when you're running Puppet Server, you're using Puppet Server 2.6.0 with Puppet 4.7.0 from `puppet-agent`. The server will have access to all of the language features from Puppet 4.7.0.

In short: you're using Puppet 4.7.0 for the server and agent. Trust `puppet --version`.

Comment: Hi Dominic, read the link and it cleared the doubt once it for all. Thanks for the detailed explanation.